# How do you create an alias in Cocoa? Is a symlink good enough?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I couldn't find a convenient way to create an alias, so I went with a symlink. I'm worried that that might not be good enough. Maybe the icon doesn't show on some versions of OS X or something like that.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createSymbolicLinkAtPath:aliasPath withDestinationPath:destPath error:nil];
```

Is this sort of thing the best I can do?
http://www.danandcheryl.com/2009/08/how-create-alias-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an alias, take a look at NDAlias, at http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NDAlias

Comment: That looks good. Unfortunately, I can't use it for above me licensing reasons, but fortunately symlinks appear good enough for my case.

Answer (score 12):

The answer depends on if you're using OS X 10.5 or 10.6. In 10.6, the old AliasManger has been replaced by `NSURL`'s bookmark data. To create an alias, given an `NSURL` instance:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToAliasTarget];
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *bookmarkData = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions: NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:nil error:&err];

if(bookmarkData == nil) {
  //handle NSError in err
} else {
  if(![NSURL writeBookmarkData:bookmarkData toURL:aliasFileURL options:NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile error:&err]) {
    //handle NSError in err
  }
}
```

As Peter Hosey points out, the bookmark data written using the `NSURL` API is not compatible with AliasManager routines. If you must support OS X < 10.6, you'll have to use the Carbon AliasManager API directly, or one of the Objective-C wrappers. I like Wolf Renstch's branch of `BDAlias`, available [here](http://github.com/rentzsch/bdalias).

Comment: Bookmark data is not an alias. If you pass that data or a bookmark file to the Alias Manager, the Alias Manager will turn up its nose at it.

Comment: (Which implies that if you take a bookmark file to a machine running Leopard or earlier, it won't work.)

Comment: @Peter, I wasn't aware that bookmark data wasn't interchangeable with AliasManager aliases. Thanks for the pointer. Feel free to edit the post appropriately. I guess this makes the case for `BDAlias` or something similar much stronger if you have to support OS X < 10.6.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too far now I'm posing this answer but it may help someone,

You can also do this like,

**Note, it's creating hard link as @zekel commented**

To create them, take a look at `linkItemAtURL:toURL:error:` and `linkItemAtPath:toPath:error:` in `NSFileManager`.

Comment: The docs say that will create a hard link which will behave much differently from an alias.

Comment: @zekel, Yeah! That's right! In my requirement, I'd to make hard link, I am removing it once my task gets done!

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can using my NSTask, Example:

```
NSArray *arr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/bin/ln" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-s", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], [arr objectAtIndex:0], nil]];
```

Comment: Use the simpler `- [NSFileManager createSymbolicLinkAtPath:withDestinationPath:error:]` instead; there's no need to launch a separate executable just to create a symlink.