# Cocoa create desktop shortcut for a folder

Tags: cocoa, shortcut-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create an alias in Cocoa? Is a symlink good enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619073/how-do-you-create-an-alias-in-cocoa-is-a-symlink-good-enough)

Does Cocoa support creating shortcut for a folder? Manually, for folders that I created, I make an alias foler for it and then drag-n-drop the alias folder to anywhwere I want on the screen. Can we do that via writing code?

Comment: With shortcut, do you mean a link? And do you mean a soft or a hard link?

Comment: It's an (folder eg) icon shows on the desktop, such that user doesn't need to go to Finder to get to the folder. Instead, double click on the folder icon on the desktop will bring him over there. does that make sense?

Comment: So you want to make an alias on the desktop?

Comment: based on the solution that Michael suggested below, seems that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is discussed in detail in:
[How do you create an alias in Cocoa? Is a symlink good enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619073/how-do-you-create-an-alias-in-cocoa-is-a-symlink-good-enough)

Comment: Got it. After creating the alias, I also want to programmingly put it on the desktop (as the desktop-shortcut on Windows). How could that be done?

Comment: I would use the 10.6 only NSURL bookmark methods mentioned in that answer if you can. To write the bookmark data to a URL, use:   [NSURL writeBookmarkData:bookmarkData toURL:aliasFileURL options:NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile error:&err]. aliasFileURL should point to something inside ~/Desktop.

Comment: @tom You should consider accepting this answer if it answers the question you posted, and if you have more questions in the same avenue you should post them as *new questions* instead of trailing a long line of follow-ups.

Comment: Lasse, make sense. thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Lasse: If another SO question answers tom's question so completely that a link to it can be the accepted answer, shouldn't this be closed as a duplicate?